# Angular2 AuthGuard e.create is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-universal

I'm experiencing a rather strange problem with authentication.
Currently, my auth guard checks to see if i am indeed authenticated. If so, it should navigate to the dashboard route.
So what happens is that I am definitely checking if i am logged in. However on the actual client page itself, the console returns an "e.create is not a function typeError". I have no idea why it does that.

```
canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.wiUser.isAuthenticated().then(status => {
            if (status) {
                console.log("maybe i'm here?");
                this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                console.log("but maybe i'm here?");
                resolve(false);//false
            } else {
                resolve(true);
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("if i get rejected do i end up here?");
            resolve(false);
        });
    });
}
```

More specifically, calling resolve(false) gets me that error. Everything else above resolve(false) gets printed, leaving me to suspect it has something to do with resolve(false)

Comment: what is e.create in your app ?

Comment: so e.create is only located in my dist files. Not sure what to do if angular2 dist is messed up

Comment: Can you do a clean install of your node modules

Comment: more information: this works with npm start, but it does not work with npm run build:prod:ngc